# Como puedo hacer que sellenium no refresque el navegador mientras el usuario se encuentre usando la pagina?

Tags: python-3.7, selenium

buen dia.

Soy nuevo en el desarollo con Python y he tratado de hacer una herramienta para mi trabajo que refresque la pagina web del workflow, para que el workflow se mantenga constantemente actualizado y no se tenga que hacer manualmente.

He tratado de hacerlo con Selenium, pero no encuentro el modo de hacer que mientras el usuario se encuentre usando la pagina no refresque, pues se necesita cierta informacion mientras se trabaja

Lo que se me ocurrio hacer es que el codigo verificara en que link esta el usuario, dado que cuando entra a verificar una orden, el link cambia y no es el que se desea refrescar, pero no encuentro la forma para que el codigo valide cual es el link actual de la pagina.

Esto es lo que llevo de codigo, muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser= webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('link de mi empresa')
while True:
    #Refreshes the web page
    time.sleep(60)
    browser.refresh()
```

Comment: Puedes obtener el link mediante JS usando `locación.href`. Otra alternativa sería usar `keyboard` para detectar pulsaciones, si se detectan pulsaciones no se recarga la página hasta que se desee.

Comment: Cuando dices JS, te refieres a combinar JavaScript con el script de Python que estoy creando o diseñar la herramienta directamente en JS? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!

Comment: Selenium te permite ejecutar código de javascript con el metodo `execute_script`